# How is it possible to implement rgb color in Android

Tags: android

How can I give declared varibles to setBackgrounColor(Color.rgb(?,?,?)) method? For instance like this EditText edit1;.... edit3. 
SetBackgrounColor(Color.rgb(edit1, edit2, edit3). In general how can I implement rgb color from EditText?I have tried the following code, but display only black at any number.

```
public class DisplayColor extends Activity {
 Button display;
    EditText red;
    EditText green;
    EditText blue;
    TextView colorDisplay;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.color);
        display=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        red=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        green=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        blue=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        colorDisplay=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textiewcolor);
        display.setOnClickListener(new DisplayColorButton());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_color, menu);
        return true;
    }
    class DisplayColorButton implements OnClickListener{

        public void onClick(View arg){

            colorDisplay.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(???)); //Here inside the 
//method how can I call the declared EditTexts?
        }

    }
```

Comment: Look once more again the code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getText().toString()` to access the contents of an edit text and `Integer.parseInt()` or similar to convert it to integer.

Something like:

```
public void onClick(View arg){
    int r = Integer.parseInt(red.getText().toString());
    int g = Integer.parseInt(green.getText().toString());
    int b = Integer.parseInt(blue.getText().toString());
    colorDisplay.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you have 3 numbers, r, g and b in range 0-255, you can use this:

```
int color = 0xff000000 // opacity
   | (r << 24)
   | (g << 16)
   | b;
view.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

```
          r=Integer.parseInt(firstEdittext.getText().toString());
          g=Integer.parseInt(secondEdittext.getText().toString());
          b=Integer.parseInt(thirdEdittext.getText().toString());                        
          text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));
```